# Concatenation of strings is not in the set

Tags: combinatorics

A set $M$ contains some strings of $0$s and $1$s of length no more than $n$, in a way that if $a,b\in M$ (possibly $a=b$), then their concatenation $ab$ doesn't belong to $M$. What is the maximum size of $M$?

As an example, if $M$ only contains strings of size at least $s=\lfloor n/2\rfloor + 1$, then any concatenation has length more than $n$, so doesn't belong to $M$. This gives a set $M$ of size $2^s+2^{s+1}+\dots+2^n=2^{n+1}-2^s$.

Comment: If two strings in $M$ can be identical then let $M$ be the set containing an infinite number of the string "0". Then there is no limit to the size of $M$.

Comment: Please see edit -- hope it's more clear. Strings in $M$ cannot be identical.

Comment: By saying $M$ is a *set* of strings, not a multiset, there are not multiple strings 0 to concatenate.

Comment: @coffeemath Thank you for pointing that out. I was confused by "if $a,b\in M$ (possibly a=b)".

Comment: @Karo Doesn't your example work for all sets? If you try to augment the set in your example with a string of length $k\lt \frac{n}{2}$ you would have to remove its complement from the set of strings of length $n-k$. This would mean that any string you tried to add would result in a string being removed.

Comment: @JohnDouma I guess if $M$ had the length 1 string 0 in it, then using the "possibly a=b" clause $M$ should not have the string 00 in it. Also seems OP's question is about constructing specific sets $M$ of strings which are "anticlosed" under contatenation, and how large they might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your construction has the maximum size, $2^{n+1}-2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor+1}.$

For each word $w$ of length $|w|\leq n/2$ we can define a word $w'$ of length $n-|w|:$
$$w'=0^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor-|w|}w 1^{\lceil n/2\rceil-|w|}$$
then define sets
$$I_w=\{w,w',ww'\}.$$

This construction ensures that the sets $I_w$ are disjoint as $w$ ranges over all words of length at most $n/2.$ And each of the $1+2+\dots+2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ sets $I_w$ contains some element not in $M.$ Therefore $M$ is missing at least this many words, so your construction is optimal.